# I wonder how I can show my Facebook feed on my own website?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I wonder if it is possible to fetch a feed from a page that I am admin for.

I have created a app and I understand how the graph explorer work. But I don't understand how to display the feed (or fetch the posts) to my website.

I have looked into this and tried multiple things but I can't get it to work.

Comment: What _exactly_ can’t you get to work? Please go read [ask]. We expect you to give us a _specific_ problem description here, including the code that causes the problem. (This is rather not a place to ask for tutorials, or that someone find the right documentation for you.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about FB javascript SDK but I researched this Url https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/realtime/ here FB provides webhook for real-time notifications

You have to subscribe to your FB app with a backend server so that any realtime notification, feeds, comments, and likes directly reach your server. Facebook calls your backend API and sends real-time feeds.

Now once you have feeds then you can either ping backend at a certain interval to check for any new feeds or from backend itself you can control frontend and display immediately.

Hope this helps you.